# installLocation identifier not found in eclipse Android package

Tags: android

when I tried to add

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml file I found the following error in eclipse

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute "installLocation" in package "android"
```

how to overcome this problem ?

edited :

My Manifest file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    package="com.xxxx.yyyy">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name=".StarterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="GamePlayActivity"></activity>

                <activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="LoginActivity"></activity>

                <activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="SignupActivity"></activity>

    <activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="MainMenuActivity"></activity>
    <activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="InfoActivity"></activity>

    <activity
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:name="ViewScoreActivity"></activity>    



    <activity 
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>

  </application>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    />


</manifest>
```

error is showing in line 
    android:installLocation="auto"

Thanks

Comment: whats your application's minSDKVersion?

Comment: i've added the manifest @user370305

Comment: and what about if you try it on android:minSdkVersion="8" or greater.

Comment: remains the same @ user370305

Comment: change your application's api version from properties make it 8 or greater. then its work fine. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: that was the solution for me.. thx :=)) user370305

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>

Introduced in: API Level 8.
```

**Backward Compatibility**

The ability for your application to install on the external storage is a feature available only on devices running API Level 8 (Android 2.2) or greater. Existing applications that were built prior to API Level 8 will always install on the internal storage and cannot be moved to the external storage (even on devices with API Level 8). However, if your application is designed to support an API Level lower than 8, you can choose to support this feature for devices with API Level 8 or greater and still be compatible with devices using an API Level lower than 8.

**To allow installation on external storage and remain compatible with versions lower than API Level 8:**

1. Include the android:installLocation attribute with a value of "auto" or "preferExternal" in the  element.
2. Leave your android:minSdkVersion attribute as is (something less than "8") and be certain that your application code uses only APIs compatible with that level.
3. In order to compile your application, change your build target to API Level 8. This is necessary because older Android libraries don't understand the android:installLocation attribute and will not compile your application when it's present.

When your application is installed on a device with an API Level lower than 8, the android:installLocation attribute is ignored and the application is installed on the internal storage.

**Caution**: Although XML markup such as this will be ignored by older platforms, you must be careful not to use programming APIs introduced in API Level 8 while your minSdkVersion is less than "8", unless you perform the work necessary to provide backward compatibility in your code. For information about building backward compatibility in your application code, see the [Backward Compatibility article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html).

Answer (score 2):

==>
go to **eclipse project settings** -> SEction "**Android**" and select at least **API Level 8 there**.

referenced by user "user370305" as comment:
**change your application's api version from properties make it 8 or greater. then its work fine. Look at my edited answer. – user370305 Oct 13 '11 at 8:06**

thx && good luck!
**:=)**